# How to compare images in Android (java)

Tags: java, android

I recently started learning to code with Android Studio. And I wanted a button when clicked to toggle between two images, but I cant seem to compare them.

I tried comparing them but it doesn't think they are the same.

```
  ImageView dog = new ImageView(this);
  dog.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);

  ImageView goofy = new ImageView(this);
  goofy.setImageResource(R.drawable.goofydog);

  if(img==dog)
  {
      img.setImageResource(R.drawable.goofydog);
  }
  else{
      img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by compare?  If you want to check if they're the exact same, you can check the equality of the two as a byte array.  But that returns false if even one pixel is off.  If you want to check if they're similar, you need to use AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only compare **primitive types** (String, Int, Double...) in `If` statements, if you compare object it will compare the **instance** of each object which in your case is different.

If you want to toggle between two images based on what your **imageView** is actually displaying you should compare the **Int** resources that is displayed like that :

```
Image img = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
  Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

  String current = "";

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( v-> {
       @Override
       void onClick(View v){
           if (img.getDrawable() == ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),
            R.drawable.dog, null)) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.goofyDog);
           } else {
             img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);
    }
       }
  }));
```

If you want to learn more about using objects in If statement, you can learn more about instance of object here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare images the way you are doing. If you want to toggle between two images using a button, you can simple do:

```
  Image img = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
  Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

  String current = "";

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( v-> {
       @Override
       void onClick(View v){
            if (current = "Dog") {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);
                current = "Dog";
            } else {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.goofydog);
                current = "Goofy";
            }
       }
  }));
```